# Twin Prime Constant

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, constants

How would one prove that the twin prime constant $$C_2 = \prod_{p > 2}1-\frac{1}{(p-1)^2} > 0$$ Simply computing the product for a large number of terms isn't rigorous, and simply establishes upper bounds, rather than lower bounds.

Comment: The twin prime constant has $(p-1)^2$ in the denominator, not $p^2$.

Comment: Is the product took on all the primes, or on all the primes $p$ such that $p+2$ is a prime, too?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: All odd primes. Your (deleted) answer was essentially correct.

Comment: It is supposed to be $(p-1)^2$, not $p^2$. It was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\prod_{p > 2}\left(1-\frac{1}{(p-1)^2}\right) > \prod_{n \ge 2}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right) = \frac12$$

Comment: How do you get the second equality?

Comment: @MayankPandey: Just expand the product to three or four terms. You will see a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

$$\prod_{p>2}\left(1-\frac{1}{(p-1)^2}\right)\geq\exp\left(-\frac{6}{5}\sum_{p>2}\frac{1}{(p-1)^2}\right)\geq\exp\left(-\frac{6}{5}(\zeta(2)-5/4)\right).$$